# Trigger a class to hide meta-data of posts on WordPress blog page

Tags: wordpress

Basically on my bakery's WordPress blog page http://www.omigretchen.de/novedades/ I would like to hide the meta data displayed below each post preview. Usually I always succeed in using the console and trigger the class.

As it shows in this case I use a display:none on the class .entry-meta. Nevertheless it does not work. Does anyone has an idea what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that you've added `.entry-meta { display: none; }`? Because I don't see it. Make sure you put it where it'll be printed to the page.

A better way to do it is by editing the `archive.php` and either remove or comment the code that prints the `entry-meta` block.

Comment: Thanks so much, you led me to the solution. I had Cloudflare active on the install and w3 cache. Purging W3 Cache does not help if you do not put Cloudflare in developer mode. Works like a charm now! Thx, you made my night! Saludos desde Chile!

Comment: Glad I could help. Mark this answer as the correct to close this thread and let others know this answer helped.